# Default Captcha module is not working in Magento2

Tags: magento2, captcha

I have enabled Captcha in **Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer > Customer Configuration** under this **Captcha**. I enabled this for my Contact Us form but it throwing error while submitting like Invalid Captcha but Captcha is not showing in the Front-end so please tell me I did anything wrong. I flushed cache too.

Comment: I have checked it working very well in magento 2.1.7 are you getting any specific error

Comment: Same version i am using and while submitting form it throws invalid captcha error message but captcha is not showing in front end.I am using 3rd party theme not default one ,is this cause error?

Comment: I think because of third party party theme its causing error

Comment: Check your form.phtml `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>` is their or not

Comment: Yes that is present in that form.phtml

Comment: i have called default captcha in newsletter form but it's not display at frontend.

Comment: Try Extension then https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html